# Adding Objects to JFrame from another class?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a blackjack program for my final project in Java. I'm still very new to Java and OOD so I apologize if my problem seems very trivial to you :(

How my program works: I have three classes so far.

**main.java**
This class builds my frame and runs all the other methods.

**cards.java**
This class creates an array that holds the card values and location to picture. I have a for loop in there that auto-populates it.

**hits.java**
This class is meant to "randomly" generate a number that will represent the chosen card. The way this works is by taking the randomly created *int* and pointing it to a matching index location on the array.

I assign the value to string objects that I then try to add to a jlabel and then add that jlabel to my main frame. The code is as follows:

**hits.java**

```
// Import necessary classes.
import java.util.Random;

public class hits {
// Create random object.
Random rand = new Random();

// Declare variables.
int card;
String cardVal, cardPic;

// Instantiate the needed classes.
main s = new main();
cards t = new cards();

// Constructor for the class.
public hits() {
    // Randomly generate a number (0 - 9).
    card = rand.nextInt(10);

    // Populate the array.
    t.runCards();

    // Assign the cards according to the num. generated.
    cardVal = t.deck[card][0];
    cardPic = t.deck[card][1];
}
// Run Method
public void runHits() {
    // Add the card chosen to the GUI.
    s.a.setText("hello");
    s.dealerCards.add(s.a);
}
}
```

I have "hello" as the text for the label because I wanted to see if perhaps my array was not populating, but even that doesn't work. If it helps here is my **main.java** as well (constructor and main method):

```
// Constructor for the main class.
public main() {
    // Setup the MAIN container.
    f1.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    f1.setSize(200, 200);
    f1.add(dealerName);
    f1.add(dealerCards);
    f1.add(userCards);
    f1.add(userName);

    // Setup the inner panels.
    dealerCards.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    dealerCards.add(b);
    userCards.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 6));
    userCards.add(c);
    userCards.add(d);
}
// Build the frame.
public void GUILaunch() {
    // Display Frame
    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f1.setVisible(true);
}
// Main method.
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     // Distribute the dealer's/player's starting hands.
     hits deal = new hits();
     deal.runHits();

     // Launch the GUI
     main gui = new main();
     gui.GUILaunch();
}
```

Hopefully I have provided enough information to help you understand what's going on here. So to sum it all up: **how can i add my jlabel(from another class) holding the randomly selected card to my main frame**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the `a` attribute that you refer to like this: `s.a.setText("hello");`? Am I missing something?

Comment: that is the name of my JLabel... sorry you couldn't see it; I have it declared in my main class

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: @kleopatra already did..that name is just temp. you're not much help in ur replies so please dont even bother.....

Comment: me bothering or not - it's not your decision ;-) For your longer term success here you better play by the norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal.runHits()  adds a label to the Main object that deal owns rather than the gui object.

I would suggest the following :

Make your main class have an instance of hits and hits have an instance of the cards object...
so you get something like this

```
public class main {

private hits hits_instance

//constructor

main(){ hits_instance = new hits(); }

//this method will add your cards

public void addCards(){
// frame = whatever frame you are using
frame.add(hits_instance.getCards());

}

}

public class hits {

private cards cards_instance;

hits(){ cards_instance= new cards();}

public JLabel getCards() {return cards_instance.getCard(randomNumber);}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked by adding it to the frame from inside the main class. Unfortunately something's not working with my array and its not displaying the values... but at least i can see the string appear there. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: one last question... so there's no way I can set the value of a swing object from another class... like what I tried to achieve?

Comment: try sending the JSwing object you wish to work either as a parameter in a method or a constructor..
public void addJLabel(JFrame frame) {frame.add(label1);}

public class class1 {
private JFrame frame_to_work_with;

class1(JFrame frame) {frame_to_work_with=frame;}
}